# Image not showing in PHP but is in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have this very simple code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="nur.jpeg"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

I've put this same code in both an HTML file and a PHP file. It works in the HTML file but not the PHP one. The path is correct. I'm using localhost with XAMPP, and when I access the image online directly using its path, it still shows.

The error is only in the PHP file. What's even worse is that this exact code was working a week ago, in the exact same way. I'm unsure what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Umm, why would it work if the file extension is PHP but you wrote your code in HTML?

Comment: Can you please show how you are writing this html code in a.php file?

Comment: post your php file so we can see the code in there

Comment: Click F12 and look at the console and network

Comment: The code I've entered is literally all of the php file.
It should work because of the <html> tags.
It's a php file since I will use php to populate the page but I can't get this basic thing to work in order to move forward.

Comment: Console is empty because I don't write anything there but network is showing the image being downloaded. I'm getting that "broken jpeg" icon where the actual image should be, such as when you get when the image name/file path/etc is wrong.

Comment: It's likely that the path to your image does not correspond to where the image is located on the server.

Comment: Incidentally, the `<img>` tag "must not have an end tag", though it's probably not a solution to your problem. (See [`<img>` @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img).)